# ''Christmas star is on the tree,'' or "in the tree"?

Tags: prepositions

Is "Christmas star is **on** the tree" correct? Or, should it be "**in** the tree"?

I know "on the tree" usually is be used to something grows by the tree.

Comment: The sentence should start with "The " or "A " but it's ok otherwise.

Comment: Yes, we speak of putting Christmas decorations _on_ the tree as well as fruit growing _on_ trees.

Comment: If you’re specifying where exactly a particular Christmas star is, then “The Christmas star is on the tree” is fine (equivalent to 圣诞星在树上). If you’re describing the general situation, it’s more natural to say, “There’s a Christmas star on the tree” (树上有一颗圣诞星). It may also be more natural to use _Christmas_ to modify the tree rather than the star: “There’s a star on the Christmas tree” sounds more natural to me (though it only works if it actually _is_ a Christmas tree, of course).

Comment: Hey, this is **not** a proof-reading question. See the tag!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And what about the answer to the question?

Comment: False dichotomy. The star is atop the tree.

Comment: Decorations are placed **on** a tree. Your cat might climb up **in** the tree.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the Christmas star as the star-shaped decoration that is put on top of the Christmas tree, the correct way to phrase is "on the tree" (exactly because the star is "on top" of the tree)

If you use "in the tree" seems like the star is inside of the tree somewhere.

There is also a difference between "on the tree" and "by the tree":

- "on the tree" implies direct contact with the tree itself, like the fruits growing on the tree or the birds making nests on the tree.
- "by the tree" denotes mere proximity to the tree and not contact, so you can have daisies growing by the tree (on the ground near the tree)

Comment: The Q is about *on* vs. *in*!

Comment: @Kris that's the first part of my answer. Additionally, I pointed out the difference between "on" and "by" because of this part of the question: "I know 'on the tree' usually be used to something grows by the tree."